# Is it possible to manually fetch the buildpack on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, geodjango, heroku-toolbelt

I am trying to add a `[buildpack][1]` to my `Heroku app`

`heroku buildpacks --app appname
1. heroku/python
2. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-pgbouncer.git
3. https://github.com/beanieboi/nginx-buildpack.git
4. https://github.com/cyberdelia/heroku-geo-buildpack.git#1.3`

But deployment is failing because before `Heroku` can fetch the new buildpack it runs

`python manage.py collectstatic` and it will not proceed further. So is it possible to fetch the new buildpack maually and then trigger the deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I am using basically the same buildpacks, however the order is important. You will want the Python buildpack to be last since that is what determines that collectstatic should be run.

These are the buildpacks I use and their order:

1. https://github.com/beanieboi/nginx-buildpack.git
2. https://github.com/cyberdelia/heroku-geo-buildpack.git#1.3
3. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-pgbouncer
4. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python#v69

If that doesn't work, you can also disable collectstatic with an environment variable: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets#disabling-collectstatic. You will need to manually run collectstatic after the deployment or make it part of the Procfile, though.